# Visual Studio(C++/SDL2) nvd3dum.pdb could not be found in the selected paths

Tags: c++, visual-studio, operating-system, sdl, nvidia

Recently I had alot of graphic driver issues, so today I used Display Driver Uninstaller to remove my Nvidia drivers and do a clean install. All good, but now when I try to compile one of my programs I get the following error:
"nvd3dum.pdb could not be found in the selected paths" (exception thrown)

What I tried so far:

- reinstall the Nvidia drivers(again), since its a Nvidia file that should be the problem?
- repair visual studio and update
- download all symbols via windows server (Tools->Debugging->Symbols->Server)

I use the boost lib, SDL2(+image,audio,ttf,net),lua/c++ binding, its an "older" project created with VS2015

I tried another program(also SDL2), I get the same warning but it doesnt throw any exception and works fine.

Apparently the error is caused by a second thread:

```
LoadingScreen.start();
Stuff.Load(); //load SDLTextures
LoadingScreen.end();
```

//-----------

```
class LoadingScreen
{

public:
    LoadingScreen();

void start() {
    mIsActive = true;
    mThread = std::thread(&LoadingScreen::render, this);
    std::cout << "Start: Loading Screen" << std::endl;
}
void end() {
    mIsActive = false;
    mThread.join();
    std::cout << "End: Loading Screen" << std::endl;
}

private:
    void render()
    {
    while (mIsActive)
    {
        SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);
        mLoading.render(NULL,angle);
        SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
    angle = angle + 1.25;
}
}

int mPercent;
std::thread mThread;

bool mIsActive = true;
DefaultTexture mLoading;
};
```

Comment: Have you tried locating this file in explorer and adding it to the visualStudio paths? Or a rebuild from clean?

Comment: Reinstalling the drivers did not actually make your program more stable.  It is the kind of desperation move that very rarely turns out well.  The debugger is simply telling you that it cannot tell you anything useful about the crash.  Which is entirely normal, you don't have the NVidia source code and you'll never have the PDB for it.  Only NVidia does.  The debugger's Stack Trace window can tell you more.  You must assume that this crash is actually caused by bad code in your own program.  We can't see it from here.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer. I had to reinstall the drivers because my GPU was crashing alot, for some reason. Well anyway, apparently one of my second threads is responsible for the crashes(it worked before). Maybe you can take a look at it, I edited my main thread. Thanks anyway!